# require regex to find Tranlation keys inside the html text

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to find translation keys inside html text:
e.g. `"<p class='m-0 p-0 mx-2 d-inline-block'>{{'MEDIA_SERVER_URL' | translate}}: </p>";`

I need to find `MEDIA_SERVER_URL` in this. conditions like that

1. Should be enclosed by either single quote or Double quotes.
2. Should have all CAPS
3. Should be inside {{}} pair braces.

ChatGpt give answer like `var pattern = /{{?'([^']+?)'[\s\S]*?[A-Z_]+}?/g;`, that's not working.

Can anyone please help me. I don't have that expertise in regex to solve this myself.
Thanks

Comment: try: `\{\{?\h*['"]([A-Z_]+)['"][^{]*\}\}?`. See: https://regex101.com/r/3fAnZl/latest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The pattern is `/{{\s*(['"])([_A-Z]+)\1\s*\|\s*translate\s*}}/g` and the keys you're looking for should be in group#2.

You may go to https://regexr.com/7tnih to have a try.

Comment: Please explain how this actually solves the issue

Comment: There is an "explain" button on the web-page I provided. I think that should have been enough.

Comment: So if that link disappears over time there is no more explanation? [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: No. The question is simple enough, and the answer have already shown what kinds of regex usages are needed to solve it. It's not my responsibility to teach people how regex works.

Comment: @DarkBee though i do agree that answer should provide information i still think ChrisFu answer is fine because it does things that are specified in the question, there is no need to copy paste it over. Beside, regexr.com will probably outlast this one particular question that most people won't search for